# WordPress + Nginx + Cloudflare - Not loading properly

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cloudflare

I am trying to get Nginx, WordPress, and Cloudflare all working together. All pages outside of the home page (which isn't loading CSS of JS it seems) redirect to the IP of the droplet it's on, and throwing an error since its not secure. Any help would be most appreciated, I've now exhausted all the fixes found here and still have made no progress.

```
server {

listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl        on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;

access_log     /var/log/nginx/main.access.log;
error_log      /var/log/nginx/main.error.log;

server_name example.com www.example.com;

root /var/www/core;
index index.php;



    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }




location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

  location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

}
```

Looking to get Wordpress properly loading the https through Cloudflare.

Comment: If the nginx config correct? it seems you tried lets encrypt and cloudflare both. Secondly also share the wp-config if you have setup WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL.  You can use the "Really Simple SSL" plugin to resolve the SSL issues.

Comment: Remove the `ssl on;` statement, it is deprecated, unnecessary and currently breaks your `http` server.

Comment: Thanks, I added the let's encrypt lines per a suggestion on one of the other stack suggestions on a another question, though it didn't seem to help. Will try removing ssl on and will upload WP files for review, thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: So the ssl on removal did the trick, now get a green ssl lock. But when I click links it goes to the insecure ip address of the droplet 123.146.xx.xx.com/link and not example.com/link.